Workflow-Core: How to implement decision step and invoke from api
Scenario:
A product is created. A notification is sent to approver for approval. If approved/rejected it updates the product status in db. Trying to achieve this using Workflow-Core in .net application.
//Below is the builder:
public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder<MyData> builder)
{
    builder
         .StartWith < **CreateProductStep * *> ()
         .WaitFor("ApprovedProduct", (data, context) => data.ProductId)
         .Then < **ApproveRejectStep * *> ();
}

//These are the  workflow steps:
public class CreateProductStep : StepBody
{
    public override ExecutionResult Run(IStepExecutionContext context)
    {
        var data = context.Workflow.Data as MyData;

        Console.WriteLine($"Product created {data.ProductId} {data.IsApproved}");
        return ExecutionResult.Next();
    }
}

public class ApproveRejectStep : StepBody
{
    public override ExecutionResult Run(IStepExecutionContext context)
    {
        var data = context.Workflow.Data as MyData;

        Console.WriteLine($"Product updated {data.ProductId} {data.IsApproved}");
        return ExecutionResult.Next();
    }
}
//The  Controller:

[HttpPost("addproduct")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct([FromBody] MyData product)
{
    var workflowId = await _workflowHost.StartWorkflow("ProductWorkflow1", product);
    return Ok(new { WorkflowId = workflowId, Message = "Product added and workflow started." });
}
[HttpPost("approve-reject-product")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ApproveRejectProduct([FromBody] MyData product)
{
    await _workflowHost.PublishEvent("ApprovedProduct", product.ProductId, product);

    return Ok(new { Message = $"Product {product.IsApproved}" });
}

Expecting the WaitFor to get the context of the first step:CreateProductStep and pass it to the next step:ApproveRejectStep. Which is not happening.
What am I missing here. How can I achieve passing the context of the previous flow to the next and invoke via api.
